# Phrase query on not analyzed field not working

Tags: lucene, luke

I have a product search index with a field "productOptions", that contains serialized JSON, meaning it may contain either an empty array for products with no options, or an array with options for products with product options:

- `[]`
- `[{ optionId: "", ... }]`

When I try the query `+productOptions: "[]"` in Luke (using the StandardAnalyzer) I don't get any matches. I was under the impression that StandardAnalyzer will search not analyzed fields as long as there is an exact match - so I don't understand why I'm not getting any hits. However, if I switch over to KeywordAnalyzer I *do* get hits, but can't use KeywordAnalyzer since I'm querying product options as part of a more complex search query that requires StandardAnalyzer.

How can I write a query that finds all products with no options (i.e. productOptions == [])?

**Note**: I have no control over the indexing process, so I can't control the values being indexed.

Comment: Okay, you couldn’t control indexing, but do you have understanding of what kind of analyzer is used during indexing?

Comment: @Mysterion since the entire indexing process happens in a third party plugin which in turn uses Umbraco Examine I can't be 100% sure, but from what I've seen in the source code it should be the StandardAnalyzer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the following, **StandardAnalyzer** effectively removes `[]` and leave this field with just empty string.

This makes searching later the same string `[]` - impossible to find anything.

One of the possibilities to achieve finding those “empty” strings is to search for `-field_name:[* TO *]`, which means the following:

`field_name:[* TO *]` is a hacky workaround to search for any documents which contains anything but empty in this field and `-` is effectively negating this condition and ultimately asking for all documents which contains empty data in the `field_name`

Comment: Hmm, I get you're saying, but this returns no hits at all in Luke... when I look at the document in Luke I can see that it still has the value []. Does StandardAnalyzer remove the [] when indexing or when querying?

Comment: Luke could only show stored values (which means original, not analyzed)